# JSF SelectOneMenu model value is not set

Tags: jsf

JSF SelectOneMenu model value is not set but I don't know what to do.

Here are my code.

header.xhtml

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bb.loginUser}">
　<f:selectItems value="#{bb.getAllUser()}"/>
　<f:ajax event="change"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Bb.java

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Bb implements Serializable{

@EJB
TimeCardFacade tcDb;
@EJB
UserFacade usrDb;

@Id
private Integer user_id;
private String user_name;

private User loginUser;
public String startWork(){
    String time1 = ***set current time***;
    User usr = loginUser;　
    TimeCard tc = new TimeCard("startWork",time1,usr);
    usr.addTimeCard(tc);
    tcDb.create(tc);
    return "timeCard?faces-redirect=true";
}
public List<User> getAllUser(){
    return usrDb.findAll();
}

***loginUser setter and getter***
```

when I go to the next page, I get NPE error.
I did a debug and found out "loginUser" is null.

Can anyone help, please?
Thank you.

Comment: *"I did a debug and found out "loginUser" is null."* ... So that's the cause.  Now look for the reason that the setter is not being called on that object, or if it is being called ... why it is being called with a `null` argument.  Hint: it you expect the value to be injected, check that you have declared it appropriately.

Comment: You should not tag JSF / CDI question with Java unless you can replicate your question in a main method (which makes it not a JSF question). Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Indeed. Do not tag [jsf] questions with [java]. They are unlikely to properly understand these. I fixed the dupe target to the proper one.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you Stephen. I still don't know where to check. I thought when I select 'loginUser' from select-one-menu, loginUser would be updated, but actually it wasnt happened and 'null'. What do I miss?

Comment: I edited my question ( added code that i didnt write ). Also my web application has db package which has AbstractFacade.java, UserFacade.java, TimeCardFacade.java ( 
auto generated with NetBeans function ). Thank you.